# Highchart: Center text in plot option in column chart

Tags: javascript, css, charts, highcharts

```
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
               formatter: function () {
                return '<b >'+Math.round(this.point.y)+'%</b>'+'<br>
                        <b >(N='+ this.point.count + ')</b>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to display 5%,1%,0% in the center of the column/center above (N=600)

[image: Here is the image]

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2a1yk8cn/)

Answer (score 3):

Add useHTML and center the element.

Ref [Highcharts Labels and String Formatting](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting#html)

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function () {
    return '<center><b>'+Math.round(this.point.y)+'%</b></center>'
      +'<br><center><b>(N='+ this.point.count + ')</b><center>';
}
```

if you wanna exporting, then add following allowHTML in exporting.

```
exporting: {
    allowHTML: true
}
```

Ref [Highcharts exporting API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting)

Comment: It works fine for screen but in export it comes little bit on right side.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Rockie Yang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2015518/rockie-yang)'s code, I found that you need to add the exporting property allowHTML and make it true. It's false by default and allowHTML allows you to preserve HTML structure in the exported chart.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/henrikskar/oos3bqov/

```
exporting: {
        enabled: true,
        allowHTML: true
    }
```